# One Disqus comments for all urls

Tags: query-string, disqus

I have Disqus comments on this [page](http://micro.jcubic.pl/) but comments don't show up when the page have query string like when someone visit from twitter or buffer (it have query string):

```
?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=bufferc1465&utm_medium=twitter
```

I have this in js:

```
var disqus_shortname = 'jmicro';
```

and there is no `window.location` anywere. How can I make Disqus comments work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it (disqus help respond on twitter) you need to set `disqus_identifier` variable, more info [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472095-how-do-i-load-the-same-thread-of-comments-on-multiple-pages-).

Comment: How about when comments are already there, being hidden one from each other because query parameters where different when the comment was written?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger if you mean that you had configured with real url with query string and want to display it on without query string? You can ask on disqus maybe there is a way to migrate comments.

Comment: i have disqus_identifier variable set but still the same problem.